# Iframe youtube autoplay is not working in mobile?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

When I run it in desktop its okay , but when I do inspect element and change to mobile view it doesn't work the autoplay.

iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vsSQEUSQkIs?autoplay=1" allow='autoplay'>

That is the iframe Im using putting ?autoplay=1 makes it work autoplay to desktop, but not working on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

What about your experience with actual Phones?

In my experience autoplay doesn't work with iOS Safari, however Chrome on an Android phone does seem to work.

I think Safari has some inbuilt prevention for videos autoplaying.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers have been making it harder for videos to autoplay on mobile, to prevent involuntary data use. It's most of two years since the question was asked but it was true even then.

The [YouTube Iframe API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations) says:

> The HTML5  element, in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome and Safari), only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a user interaction (such as tapping on the player). Here's an excerpt from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html)
>
> > "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."